# How do I avoid this useless message?

Tags: security-warning

I am using Linux Fedora 20, (but working towards upgrading), Mate desktop and Maxthon, which is automatically started up when I switch on. Most times when I begin I get the ridiculously useless screen image shown here.

[image: http://imgur.com/0jBWjHr]

How can I respond sensibly or avoid this

---

Thank you DKing for your comment It does come up when listing the "Last session",but there is a vast amount of stuff there. I call it useless because it does not specify the actual site that has the link to bajee.org, so I cannot  remove that specific reference. I do close that tab and all then seems well, not a big problem but a niggle.

---

Responding to Ouroborus request (thanks for that) clicking the "Advanced" link leads to a similar screen that offers two options, one is to press on regardless, and the other goes on to a third screen, shown in this image: [http://i.imgur.com/73onhnA.png](https://i.imgur.com/73onhnA.png),

Again no useful information is provided as there is still no detail on which specific site contains the dangerous reference.

Comment: What does the "advanced" link, next to the button, give you?

Answer (score 3):

From what I gather, your browser is attempting to re-open it's last session, which seems to be for the website bajee.org, which is suspected for malware.

I didn't want to visit that domain myself, just in case, but I searched Google, since they often report malware. Google didn't seem to have a link to it, which is not a good indication.

I am not certain what you mean when you say that the message is useless. It is a good feature for browsers to report potentially dangerous sites. Most browsers have an option to disable this. I am not familiar enough with Maxthon to know how to do this, but you may want to try checking the settings, and then contact their support.

Alternately, you may just want to be sure not to visit that suspicious site. If that was the last session, then be sure to close out all of your tabs, and start over, without viewing that site.